# How to detect if field support multi values?

Tags: 7, entities

It seems that [field_info_instance](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7) doesn't return such info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the 'cardinality' is stored at the field (base) and not the field instance.  You should be able to use [field_info_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) to retrieve that information.